# How to send SMS using FASTSMS in c# windows application

Tags: c#, sms

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.fast2sms.com/dev/wallet?authorization=[API KEY]&sender_id=FSTSMS&message='"+textBox2.Text+"'&route=p&numbers='"+textBox1.Text+"'");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }

    }
```

---

I need to send sms using C# windows application by FAST2SMS

I am using a webbrowser tool in c# to navigate,

Answer (score 0):

Example taken from [.NET Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netstandard-2.0). HttpClient is available since .Net 4.5 and is also part of NetStandard

```
static async Task Main()
{
   // Create a New HttpClient object.
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

   // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions
   try  
   {
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below
      // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

      Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
   }  
   catch(HttpRequestException e)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!"); 
      Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
   }

   // Need to call dispose on the HttpClient object
   // when done using it, so the app doesn't leak resources
   client.Dispose(true);
}
```